# 1980s or 90s Movie and TV show. A few men build a barn yard rocket with new propulsion fuel

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

Originally a movie (maybe a Made for TV movie) filmed in USA. Later made into a TV series, which probably only lasted 1 season. [I don't know if any one of the main characters were in both the movie and the series, although I think the old man/grandpa character was in both.]

Essentially they build a rocket ship powered by a constant thrust fuel, and in the movie, I am pretty sure fly it to the moon, land and return to earth.

There was a old man, a young ex-NASA? engineer, and the old man's daughter or grand daughter (maybe the Engineer's was her husband or boy friend, or soon to be love interest) There may have been a few more people involved but I cant remember)

The TV series was a "launch to go help someone" every week type shows. (never leaving the Earth/Moon area) In fact I am pretty sure most of the "flights" were Earth to Earth hops helping someone in remote areas. The series was pretty bad is all I remember.

I recall one specific scene from the movie. But little else.
The Engineer was demonstrating to the old man the difference between NASA's propulsion system and His propulsion system (I think NASA said it was to dangerous and was not interested it testing it. Which was why he was ex-NASA)

They were in a little convertible sports car with a LOT of Horsepower. The engineer is the driver and they are on an airport runway. He says to the old man. "This is how NASA gets to the moon." He then floors the accelerator pops the clutch and races through the gears saying "First Stage" "Second Stage" "Third Stage" as he shifts gears until they are at  about 100mph, and then puts the gear in neutral and coasts and says "now we sit in zero gee until we coast to the moon" and when they reach the end of the runway he breaks to a stop and says "now we are on the moon."

Then he turns the car around and says "This how WE will get to the moon" The old man hangs on tight to the seatbelt and car door, but the Engineer just gently slowly accelerates the car up to about 60-70mph, and says "when we are halfway there we turn around and just as slowly decelerate" and he puts light pressure on the brakes to slow down.

He explains about constant thrust acceleration and that his fuel is VERY efficient and dies not need NASA's staging system, their rocket only needs 1 stage.

This is really about all I remember from the movie or series.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l412qlmBJxI

Comment: They flew to the moon to salvage materials left by the Apollo astronauts.  And the sports-car scene wasn't on an airport runway, it was an auto racetrack.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The movie was "Salvage" - the series "Salvage 1".  Andy Griffith played the old guy, Joel Higgins was the pilot and Trish Stewart was the rocket fuel expert.

(I watched this one as a kid - an early episode invented something like "fracking" as I recall, making gasoline extremely cheap).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvage_1 has more details and points out that they got a second season.

Comment: YES!!! That is it. More or less what I remembered. The movie is on YouYube. Here is a the part I remembered: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUDJ4pJb248&t=812s

Comment: Looks like the "Movie" was the 2 hour pilot episode.

Comment: Yeah.  A lot of TV movies are attempted pilots.  If they succeed there will be a series; if they fail, at least  the network got a movie to fill a couple of hours of time.

Comment: I watched this at the time, but not since.  I remember it with great fondness and will be watching it on Youtube (Thx NJonny!) tomorrow!